# Using variable reference with get-WMIObject and interrogateservice method

Tags: powershell

I am using Get-WMIObject with class Win32_Service to get a reference to a service. I am storing that reference in a variable. My question is, can I just use the reference variable to get an update on the state of the service, or do I need to perform another Get-WMIObject?

Currently I use this:

```
$parameters = @{
        Class = 'Win32_Service'
        ComputerName = $server
        Credential = $script:credentials
        Filter = "Name='$ServiceName'"
    }
$targetservice = Get-WMIObject @parameters
$results = $targetservice.startservice()
if($results.returnvalue -eq 0)
{
    do
    {
        start-sleep -milliseconds 100
     } until((Get-WMIObject @parameters).state -eq 'Running')
}
```

Do I need to make that second call to Get-WMIObject, or can I do it like this?

```
$parameters = @{
        Class = 'Win32_Service'
        ComputerName = $server
        Credential = $script:credentials
        Filter = "Name='$ServiceName'"
    }
$targetservice = Get-WMIObject @parameters
$results = $targetservice.startservice()
if($results.returnvalue -eq 0)
{
    do
    {
        start-sleep -milliseconds 100
        $targetservice.interrogateservice()
     } until(($targetservice).state -eq 'Running')
}
```

I know the interrogateservice is suppose to update the state of the service but for some reason it is not working as you would think and gets stuck in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

WMI results only reflect the status at the time the query was performed. You need to re-run `Get-WmiObject` to get the current status.

Comment: Seems redundant to have to do that, but I guess it is what it is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You were close.. unfortunately InterrogateService does not update the $targetservice object but it does have its own return code that you can use to determine the state.

so you can have a if statement like:
if ($targetservice .InterrogateService().ReturnValue -ne 6) {"Failed to stop"}

For the return codes look at the below Microsoft reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/interrogateservice-method-in-class-win32-service

... but yea I would just make another WMI call as the return codes are not that straight forward... I believe it gives a 0 if the state isn't changed from the original. So you would have to account for that.